# Variable in a list datastep SAS

Tags: list, sas, datastep

Suppose that I have the following list

```
    proc sql;
    select name into: list separated by ' ' from dataset;
    quit;
```

and I want to keep the elements of this list in my dataset2. The datastep

```
    data dataset2;
    set dataset2;
    if name in &list.;
    run;
```

does not work. How should I modify the first proc sql so that the datastep makes sense? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you're looking to filter values **within** a column, not the number of columns.

If the value is numeric this is what you need:

```
data dataset3;
set dataset2;
if name not in (&list.);
run;
```

If the value is character then this is what you need:

```
proc sql;
select quote(name) into: list separated by ' ' from dataset;
quit;

data dataset3;
set dataset2;
if name not in (&list.);
run;
```

Comment: When I use the quote() function, the list appears empty, but without quote() it appears with all its elements. Do you know why this could be happening? Name takes char values.

Comment: Post the exact code and the log.

Comment: I wouldn't select things into a list- If you want the distinct names, for example, I would select those into a table.  It really isn't clear what OP ultimately wants to accomplish.